# Javascript Regex min length matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have found some regex which works for start of string but I can't seem to find a way to make it only search after 2 characters have been input. Is this a regex problem or will it need to be done in the code? 
    RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");

Comment: if (foo.length>2) ......

Comment: `if (input.value.length >= 2) { /* do your search */ }`

Comment: Replace `"^"` with `"^.."`

Comment: I used the if (foo.length>2) way and it works how I would like thank you

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work.
 
You can also use https://Regex101.com to test your regular expressions

```
 /^(.){2}/
```

I would suggest using a foo.length > 2 though unless you absolutely *need* regex.